# Call method from repository in controller (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a repository, where I have this method for getting some data. Here is the code:

```
public List<HeatmapViewModel> GetStops()
{
    using (var ctx = new GoogleMapTutorialEntities())
    {
        List<HeatmapViewModel> items = new List<HeatmapViewModel>();

        #region firstitem_calculation
        var firstitem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(
            x => new Logging
            {
                Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
                Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
                CurDateTime = x.CurDateTime
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        var midnight = new DateTime(firstitem.CurDateTime.Year, firstitem.CurDateTime.Month, firstitem.CurDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
        TimeSpan difference = (firstitem.CurDateTime - midnight);
        var difference_after_midnight = (int) difference.TotalMinutes;

        items.Add( new HeatmapViewModel
        {
            FirstStartDifference = difference_after_midnight
        });
        #endregion

        return items;
    }
}
```

I need to call this method in controller, in this method:

```
public JsonResult GetStops()
{
}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: you can make the method as static and then you can easily call it by `var details = YourNameSpace.RepositoryName.GetStops()` or by initiating a new instance of the repository and then you call the method as `var repo=new YourNameSpace.RepositoryName(); var details = repo.GetStops();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
YourRepositoryName repo = new YourRepositoryName();
var _data = repo.GetStops();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult GetStops()
{
    var repo = new TheRepository();
    var listOfHeatMapVm = repo.GetStops();

    //Convert the list of HeatMapVm to Json result here.
    return Json(listOfHeatMapVm);
}
```

Comment: controllers call services and services use repositories